# Подключение JS и CSS в Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, javascript, css, laravel

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли возможность в Laravel подключать автоматически для каждого контроллера свой индивидуальный `.js` файл ? (не через верстку и шаблонизатор). Так, что бы к примеру, если имя контроллера `CarsController.php` , то автоматически из директории `../public/js` подключался скриптовый файл с именем `Cars.js` ? А то если все пихать в один общий файл `dashboard.js` со всех контроллеров, то он получается шибко большим...

Comment: Я знаю что через `@yield` можно это делать, сам так подключил главный скриптовый файл и прочии библиотеки. Дело в том, что я Ларавелом начал заниматься совсем не долго, до этого CodeIgnitor. И там был один замечательный функционал, позволяющий запускать дополнительные файлы (css, js) по имени котроллера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть два способа:

1) Сделать `@yield('scripts')` в футере основного шаблона и потом в каждом шаблоне(конечной страницы)  просто грузить необходимый скрипт.

2) Если используете vuejs или react и так поддерживают (или есть плагины для lazy-load компонентов), исходя из маршрутов.

Не знаю какой у вас проект, но если вы используете blade то пользуйтесь @yield для вставки css и скриптов под каждую страницу